# ASP.NET Core Identity as UI base URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Identity URLs are all of the form : `/Identity/Account/Login` etc

How can I change them (all) to be of the form `/myapp/Identity/Account/Login` etc ?

Is there a single "base" property or setter ?

(using latest .NET Core 3 preview 8)

Answer (score 1):

The default UI uses Razor Pages, and by convention, the URLs are based on the filesystem path, similar to how Web Forms used to work back in the day. In other words, that's the URL because the page is literally located at `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml` (the `Areas` and `Pages` portions of the path are logical, and removed from the URL by convention, leaving just `/Identity/Account/Login`.

If you want to modify this, you'll need to specify custom routes, via something like:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/Account/Login", "Login");
    });
```

You can also change the route on the actual page via the `@page` directive in the cshtml file:

```
`@page "Login"`
```

However, for the Identity UI, that approach would require you to scaffold the page into your project, obviously, in order to be able to change that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in my question I want to _add_ a path not remove it, that is I want to use `/myapp/Identity/Account/Login` .. can you please edit your answer to reflect this ?

Answer (score 1):

For chaning Razor Page route, you could try [Use a parameter transformer to customize page routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-a-parameter-transformer-to-customize-page-routes)

Detail steps below:

1. `IdentityParameterTransformer`

   ```
   public class IdentityParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
   {
       public string TransformOutbound(object value)
       {
           if (value == null) { return null; }

           // Slugify value
           if (value.ToString().StartsWith("Identity"))
           {
               return $"/MyApp/{ value.ToString() }";
           }
           return value.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register

   ```
   services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
   {
       options.Conventions.Add(
           new PageRouteTransformerConvention(
               new IdentityParameterTransformer()));
   });
   ```